# I'm famously rectangular

Tags: riddle

> I'm famously rectangular
>
> Sometimes it's dark
>
> Sometimes it's not
>
> I'm penetrable and deep
>
> I'm a joy for the kids
>
> But if you use me while I'm wet,
>
> You might get killed!

Comment: Was the change from "I'm" to "it's" intentional or not?

Comment: @rschwieb it was definitely deliberate. Yes.

Comment: Tiananmen Square

Comment: I think this question is way too broad to get a right answer (as evidenced by the numerous answers below). I flagged as such, but it was declined.

Comment: Sorry flagging and upvoting this at the same time: Upvote for a nice riddle, flagging for being to broad... sorry!

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Okay, I think now is the right time to answer my own question.

I am a

> Swimming pool.

I'm famously rectangular

> Most swimming pools appear rectangular.

Sometimes it's dark / Sometimes it's not

> This is mostly referring to day and night but also to swimming pools having lights.

I'm penetrable and deep

> You can penetrate a swimming pool by jumping into the water (diving) and they tend to be deep.

I'm a joy for the kids

> Children are fond of swimming in the pool in a hot summer day.

But if you use me while I'm wet, you might get killed!

> You can die of drowning in a water filled pool if you can't swim.

Comment: This was my first guess but I gave up when I see the other answers. Have never thought that this turned out to be the correct answer Sad :(

Comment: @OmegaKrypton: I also thought about a swimming pool, but thought the answer would have to be different.

Comment: I also suspected the "dangerous when wet" was camouflaging this, but they're as likely to be circular or curvy, so it seemed like a weak candidate.  "Penetrable and deep" also does not really put the nail the coffin for the "solution" either. Nice try, but keep refining your puzzle-writing skill :) . ( I have to confess, my level is not even *this* high :P)

Comment: This was my original guess as well, but I felt that "Sometimes it's dark / Sometimes it's not" is too much of a stretch for a swimming pool. I suspect that probably threw a lot of people off, considering that there were 26 answers and no one got it.

Comment: Also a big stretch to say that drowning in general is "getting killed."

Comment: It's the pool talking. The pool "kills" you.

Answer (score 48):

Are you

> a flag ?

I'm famously rectangular

> flags are famous (country or other localities flags) and rectangluar (except a few, e.g. [Nepal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KidJIwJicnY&t=1s))

Sometimes it's dark

> e.g. pirate flag

Sometimes it's not

> e.g. white flag

If you use me while I'm wet, you might get killed!

> WETFLAG is an acronym for steps to take for first aid for children in medical emergency, see e.g. [here](https://emergencypedia.com/kidsresus/) : Weight Electricity Tube Fluid Lorazepam Adrenaline Glucose

Comment: Wow, that last spoiler is an interesting take...

Comment: Gets an awesome-if-true vote for the last spoiler.  I don't think it's the answer, but it deserves an upvote anyway.

Comment: I like this answer quite a lot. However, it's not the correct answer.

Comment: True. Was just an excuse to link to that youtuber which regularly makes fun of that specific example (his videos being one of the reason "rectangular" made me think of this proposition in fact).

Comment: Also, please censor your commment to avoid spoilers ;)

Comment: Psst, the flag of [switzerland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Switzerland) isn't strictly a rectangle, but a square

Comment: 1.. A square is a rectangle. 2. There, I edited my answer to prevent further comments of this type :)

Comment: @MindSwipe the flag of [Nepal](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drapeau_du_N%C3%A9pal) is neither rectangular nor square :)

Comment: @Flying_whale I know, but as a swiss person, I just wanted to point out how special we are :P . I mean we even convinced the United Nations that our Flag should be square in front of the UN building in Geneva.  
P.S is your name a reference to Gojiras song "Flying Whale"?

Comment: @MindSwipe haha "guys we don't want your mainstream rectangular flag, look at our glorious square " :D . Yep my nickname is a reference to Gojira, I really like this band and I liked the duality light/heavy in the concept of a flying whale :)

Answer (score 45):

Are you a

> Toaster?

I'm famously rectangular

> Most toasters are basically rectangular, as is most toast

Sometimes it's dark
Sometimes it's not

> Bread can be toasted a lot or a little

If you use me while I'm wet
You might get killed!

> A toaster in the bathtub can be a shocking experience

Comment: At that rate, why a "toaster" especially?  One would think that simply power outlet units are more consistently rectangular than toasters...

Comment: @Outman When you respond to the answer and state the answer itself, it kinda defeats the purpose of the spoiler formatting.

Comment: @rschwieb It's a trope by now. I don't know if [Groundhog Day](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-kohfPAzj8) was the first, but it's one of the most famous.

Answer (score 27):

> Lightswitch?

```
I'm famously rectangular
```

> Lightswitch plates are almost ALWAYS rectangular, as is the protruding piece you flick.

```
Sometimes it's dark
```

> Light off

```
Sometimes it's not
```

> Light on

```
If you use me while I'm wet
```

> This has happened to me

```
You might get killed!
```

> Electricty across the heart can be a real bummer, eh

Comment: I would have given the same answer. Have a +1

Comment: Good answer, but someone else already posted this.  In the future you should check the other answers to make sure yours is not a duplicate.

Comment: @BenJ More people seem to like this one than the other. Perhaps he thought he could give a more complete answer?

Answer (score 11):

Are you a

> Handkerchief

I'm famously rectangular

> It's also known as a pocket square

Sometimes it's dark

> Different colors or designs, or perhaps blood

Sometimes it's not

> Lighter colors, OR could be a wordplay— "sometimes it's snot"

If you use me while I'm wet You might get killed!

> Wet meaning already used by someone else. Especially in older times, such poor hygiene would spread disease and death.

Answer (score 8):

Are you:

> Spongebob Squarepants?

I'm famously rectangular

> He is a famous rectangle. All squares are rectangles.

Sometimes it's dark

> Spongebob can have a dark sense of humor sometimes.

Sometimes it's not

> The show can also be really lighthearted at times.

I'm penetrable and deep

> He is filled with penetrable holes. And lives deep in the ocean.

I'm a joy for the kids

> It's a kids show

But if you use me while I'm wet,

You might get killed!

> If you pour water on your TV, you might get electrocuted

Comment: That fits the pants!

Answer (score 6):

Are you a

> Display screen

I'm famously rectangular

> Screens are nearly always rectangular, to the extent that the phrase "square eyes" is used to derogatorily refer to someone who spends too much time looking at one.

Sometimes it's dark

> Screens are black when off.

Sometimes it's not

> They're bright with light when they're in use.

If you use me while I'm wet
You might get killed

> Like any electrical equipment, screens are typically dangerous when exposed to water.

Comment: You should mention how the answer relates to each of the lines in the question

Comment: @somebody can't be bothered. flag if if you don't like it.

Comment: Not flag-worthy, just... if it's wrong there's nothing OP can really do to help point you in the right direction

Answer (score 6):

Are you:

> Colorado?

I'm famously rectangular.

> Colorado the state is about as close to rectangular as a piece of the Earth's surface can get, and appears rectangular in several map projections.

Sometimes it's dark / Sometimes it's not.

> COLOR ado?  Or maybe, referring to appearance of the river in various places or at various times?

If you use me while I'm wet / You might get killed.

> In many parts of the Colorado River nowadays, if there's more than a trickle then it's likely because of flash flooding.

Answer (score 6):

Are you a

> light switch

I'm famously rectangular

> most are

Sometimes it's dark

> when its off

Sometimes it's not

> when its on

If you use me while I'm wet
You might get killed!

> Well, some people think that

Answer (score 5):

I don't know that I really like this answer but are you a

> road

I'm famously rectangular

> Roads are long rectangles (until they bend)

Sometimes it's dark
Sometimes it's not

> Outside when you are driving

If you use me while I'm wet
You might get killed!

This is what lead me down the path to this answer...

> I was thinking of the slippery when wet signs you see on roads, at least in the US

Answer (score 4):

Are you:

> a mobile phone?

Rectangular in shape, mostly black or dark colors, and can kill if used when wet!

Comment: I can't see any way that a [answer here] could kill if wet. Maybe if you shorted the battery and that causes a fire.

Comment: My [answer] is waterproof.

Answer (score 4):

You're

> Wall Socket

Famously Rectangular

> Wall Socket are Rectagular

Sometimes it's dark
Sometimes it's not

> Some Wall Socket have light on them. Also it can be reference that you
>  can plug a light into it.

I'm penetrable and deep

> You can plug into wall socket.

I'm a joy for the kids

> Kids like put their fingers into wall sockets.

But if you use me while I'm wet,
You might get killed!

> water + electricity = dead

Comment: From all the answers I've seen, this one comes the closest to matching all hints. But "a joy for the kids" is still a bit of a stretch, I think OP intended a different solution.

Answer (score 3):

I'm thinking you're:

> [Cruise control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cruise_control)

I'm famously rectangular

> Indeed. Almost every card driver knows it.

While not all are in a rectangular shape but some are:

> [image]

Sometimes it's dark

Sometimes it's not

> Depending on how your cruise control paint color. And the brightness inside your car.

If you use me while I'm wet

You might get killed!

> If you use it on rain, well you risk of accident as stated [here](https://lifehacker.com/why-you-shouldn-t-use-cruise-control-in-the-rain-1572057920). Everyone know you risk your life when having an accident.

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> an electrical circuit with a light bulb and a switch?

```
I'm famously rectangular
```

> Circuits drawn on paper or digital images (used for example in learning books) almost always have a rectangular shape.

```
Sometimes it's dark
Sometimes it's not
```

> When the switch is off, a light bulb does not receive energy and is also off, so "it's dark" (this explains why there is "it's dark", not "I'm dark")

```
If you use me while I'm wet
You might get killed!
```

> Of course, this is about a risk of electric shock.

Answer (score 3):

Are you a

> Zebra crossing

I'm famously rectangular

> The Beatles walked across one in Abbey Road and the lines are rectangular

Sometimes it's dark

> The black lines

Sometimes it's not

> The white lines

If you use me while I'm wet
You might get killed!

> They can become slippery while wet and if you fall you might get hit by a car

Summed up in this image:

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you are

> A phone

I am famously rectangular

> Non rectangular phones are rare

Sometimes it's dark

> The screen when the phone is turned off

Sometime it's not

> The screen when the phone is turned on

If you use me while I'm wet, you might get killed

> A phone contains electricity, so it can be dangerous

Comment: I'd like to see anyone dying from 5V or 3.3V DC! In fact, such low voltage can't even be felt.

Answer (score 2):

Here I go~

You are a

> Dance floor!

I am famously rectangular

> Dance floors are pretty rectangular, especially those with checkered light patterns you see in disco clubs.

Sometimes it's dark
Sometime it's not

> Places with a dance floor usually have lights flickering on and off.

If you use me while I'm wet, you might get killed

> Slipping on a wet dance floor while dancing might get yourself killed.

Answer (score 2):

You are a

> trampoline

I'm famously rectangular

> There are many rectangular trampolines.

Sometimes it's dark

> It is black material.

Sometimes it's not

> It could be another color though.

I'm penetrable and deep

> They get deep when you jump down on them.

I'm a joy for the kids

> Trampolines are fun.

But if you use me while I'm wet,
You might get killed!

> It is dangerous to jump on a wet trampoline.

Answer (score 2):

> Sandbox

1. > Rectangular
2. > Fun for the kids
3. > If wet turns to quick sand

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! In the future, please hide you answer using the ">!" spoiler notation.

Answer (score 2):

I really don't think this is the answer you're looking for, but I'm going to post it anyway.

You may be a

> Roller Coaster

I'm famously rectangular

> Roller Coaster cars are typically rectangular. This could also apply to multiple cars hooked together.

Sometimes it's dark

> Some roller coasters have tunnels.

Sometimes it's not

> Some roller coasters are out in broad daylight.

I'm penetrable and deep

> The tracks can be "penetrated" through the holes between the rails. The tracks drop from a high point down into a deep valley.

I'm a joy for the kids

> Lots of youth love roller coasters!

But if you use me while I'm wet,
You might get killed!

> Heavy rain might cause some dangerous conditions for roller coasters. Also, when raining, there's potential for lighting strikes.

And per the tip in your comment, "There is climbing involved!"

> Roller coasters climb up to the tops of some of the peaks.

Answer (score 1):

Well a few people have guessed something similar to this, but not this exact object.

Are you

> A tubelight ?

```
I'm famously rectangular
```

> Tubelights are rectangular

```
Sometimes it's dark
Sometimes it's not
```

> Tubleights are notorious for flickering when initially started (thus sometimes its dark sometimes its not) [though could just be a reference to the fact they are a light with a switch]

```
If you use me while I'm wet
You might get killed!
```

> Using any electrical appliance when wet is just a bad idea

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you are allowed to give two answers, but here are two:

You might be a

> 1) TV  2) Swimming pool

I'm famously rectangular

> 1) Indeed! 2) Mostly

Sometimes it's dark
Sometimes it's not

> 1) Off/on 2) night/day

If you use me while I'm wet
You might get killed!

> 1) As any other electric devices (e.g. toasters), if they get wet and you plug them in, you might die of electrocution. 2) If I'm full up, you might drown!

Answer (score 1):

Too many similar answers. Here comes a weird one. Are you

> A pool for spent nuclear fuel near let's say a nuclear reactor

I'm famously rectangular

> Most pools are rectangular.

Sometimes it's dark

> Nearby nuclear reactor not running, all lights out. Note it doesn't say I'm dark but it's dark.

Sometimes it's not

> Reactor running, all lights on at least for security

If you use me while I'm wet

> The pool only needs to be full of water when in use

You might get killed!

> As so nicely stated in the last paragraph in [this what if](https://what-if.xkcd.com/29/) you'd die quite fast trying to swim in a pool for spent nuclear fuel while in use.

Comment: A joy for the kids ? haha

Comment: This was the closest to the answer I wanted. And I believe it's my fault for being too broad that you thought of a nuclear pool instead of a normal pool.

Comment: @Outman normal pools are booooring :P

Comment: @Joe Derksen the question was edited later. Maybe the kids enjoy it while on an excursion? BTW my school was called Derksen ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my guess

> Floor tile 
>  Rectangular, all colors design, and slippery when wet

OR

> Stairs 
>  Since climbing involved

Answer (score 0):

I actually have two guesses.  First:

> Parachute

I'm famously rectangular

> Many parachutes are rectangular, particularly the steerable ones.

Sometimes it's dark

Sometimes it's not

> Parachutes come in many colors

If you use me while I'm wet

You might get killed!

> A wet parachute may not open properly and may be too heavy, causing you to fall to your death.

---

And second:

> Blanket

I'm famously rectangular

> Blankets are almost always rectangular

Sometimes it's dark

Sometimes it's not

> Likewise, blankets come in many colors, but you've also got the point that they are generally used at night when it's dark, but also can be used in the daytime.

If you use me while I'm wet

You might get killed!

> A wet blanket can cause you to die of hypothermia.